# Polymer: Browser rendering stops while loading html import

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, polymer, html-imports

When loading a huge vulcanized html import like this:
`<link rel="import" src="elements.html"/>`
The browser rendering is completelys blocked (meaning not even a simple loading animation is possible). Adding async="true" improves the situation a bit but its terribly laggy while loading and therefore useless. 
How is it possible to show a decent loading screen to the user while doing the (a few seconds lasting) html import work?

Comment: You could always just load a small css file first and make a fullscreen loading screen before all the elements are ready.

Comment: yeah i know but I want an animated loading screen and, in addition to that, I'm doing lazy loading for some elements were a fullscreen loading screen is no option unfortunately.

Comment: Take a look [HERE](https://aerotwist.com/blog/polymer-for-the-performance-obsessed/) and [HERE](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/blob/master/docs/polymer-perf.md)